# Problem installing dnspython Airflow docker puckel

Tags: airflow

Im running the dockerfile https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile

with this extra installtions

```
&& pip install pymongo[srv] \
&& pip install dnspython \
```

The log in built command say that was success

```
+ pip install dnspython
Collecting dnspython
  Downloading dnspython-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188 kB)
Installing collected packages: dnspython
Successfully installed dnspython-1.16.0
```

But in airflow is impossible to see that dnspython was setup
But from airflow is impossible to connect in Mongo from a Pythonoperator

ERROR - The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs

```
import pymongo
import ssl

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:password@host/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
db = client.test
```

from my local machine is working

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't work, but you could try installing those two packages through Airflow [extra packages](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html#extra-package) to see if that works. The [mongo](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/setup.py#L273-L276) extra includes both `pymongo` and `dnspython`, which you can specify when you [build](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow#build) the image via the `AIRFLOW_DEPS` environment variable.

Comment: Why don't you use official airflow image? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html